# Is it possible to mix different versions of gcc and ld?

Tags: android, gcc, ld, unix-ar

My environment is arm-linux-androideabi (Android 2.2 on a Toshiba AC100). I have 2 sets of GCC compilers for my environment(installed at separate locations on the device):

1. 4.4.3 ([Android NDK on Android](http://my-android-travels.blogspot.com/2012/02/android-build-system-ndk-toolchain_21.html))
2. 4.6.0 ([R + GCC on Android](http://rwiki.sciviews.org/doku.php?id=getting-started%3ainstallation%3aandroid))

The problem I face is that the gcc-4.6.0 segfaults whenever it runs (however it runs every task successfully, just segfaulting at the end,probably in the exit routines), while ld-4.4.3 and ar-4.4.3 fail to run on my environment. On the other hand gcc-4.4.3 runs beautifully, as does ld-4.6.0 and ar-4.6.0.

Thus, while building on my device, if I run configure using 4.4.3, it'll fail at the configure step because even if the configure test programs are compiled successfully, gcc segfaults and returns a non-zero value(139). However if I run configure with 4.6.0, configure runs well enough, but the build (`make all`) fails miserably at linking and static library creation.

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to use gcc-4.4.3 to compile my object files (`gcc-4.4.3 -c input.c`) and then link with ld-4.6.0 (`ld-4.6.0 -o input input.o -lc` )? That is, I'll remove the problematic binaries and use a combination of the working binaries to build projects.
2. If there are caveats, then what are they?

Comment: Didn't try it but i wonder what libraries (headers) would compiler use and what linker will link. Probably you will have to tell them...

Comment: As soon as I posted this question, I realised I could have tried it and seen. However, as your comment demonstrates, there are a lot of caveats that I need to look into.

Answer (score -1):

You can call gcc using a shell script, to hide the bad exit code.

Comment: I already do that. However, it has a drawback that gcc wrapper will return true even if the compilation should fail, as the exit code is consistently the one returned for segmentation fault (139).

Comment: Maybe you could check if an executable was produced and return success, otherwise return an error code? Of course, the whole thing continues to be a hack...